# ASP.NET MVC 4 is ModelState.IsValid always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The problem: I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) and I can pull data from the database. I can also Delete records from the database. But when I try to create or edit I get this error:

[image: Invalid Value]

So as I was looking in the controller and I see that there is ModelState.IsValid is when I set a breakpoint to it, it is always false.

Here is my model:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models 
{
    public class Text
    {
       [Key]
       public int id { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class textDBContext : DbContext
    {
       public DbSet<Text> texts { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

My Database has two fields: "id" and "text".  "id" is of datatype int
and "text" is of datatype string.

I generated this controller from the model which also generated the views (CRUD)

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class textDBController : Controller
    {
        private textDBContext db = new textDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /textDB/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.texts.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /textDB/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Text text = db.texts.Find(id);
            if (text == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(text);
        }

        //
        // GET: /textDB/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /textDB/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Text text)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.texts.Add(text);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(text);
        }

        //
        // GET: /textDB/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Text text = db.texts.Find(id);
            if (text == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(text);
        }

        //
        // POST: /textDB/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Text text)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);


                // Breakpoint, Log or examine the list with Exceptions.
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(text).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(text);
        }

        //
        // GET: /textDB/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            Text text = db.texts.Find(id);
            if (text == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(text);
        }

        //
        // POST: /textDB/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Text text = db.texts.Find(id);
            db.texts.Remove(text);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the edit view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Text

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Text</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.text)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.text)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.text)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any validation annotations in `MvcApplication1.Models.Text`?

Comment: Remove the `[Required]` above your text properties and try again. Just to confirm what @jeroenVannevel is saying. If so you could have another validation annotations.

Comment: By the way, you do not require the [Key] attribute for id as entity framework recognises it by convention to be a primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the property name, class name, and argument name all being the same is messing up the MVC model-binding magic. If you change:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Text text)
```

to:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Text values)
```

it posts back correctly.

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks! Really appreciate it! But I one thing I am confused about is since this was generated automatically, how can we prevent it from doing this? Just watch what I name things?

Comment: The "model-binding magic" I mentioned is really the MVC framework attempting to map post-back parameters to your model. Since the post-back parameters are just a dictionary of name/value, the logic relies on unique naming to get the values where they belong. Maybe mandate that all model classes end in the word Model (e.g., TextModel) to reduce the likelihood of a collision.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks again I am very new to MVC but I am learning.

Comment: @Kevin I actually had a similar problem when I started out with MVC. I made a jQuery call to the controller, and the object parameter was named "text", and also had a property "Text", which leads to strange behaviour (you are not entering the controller at all, or if you specifiy the parameter name in jQuery, you enter it, but always get `null`). So yes, use a naming convention that counteracts this :-)

Answer (score 1):

If class name and property name is same then model binding is not mapping perperly.
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TextView(Text objtext,string text)
        { return View();  }
Here you can check, objText will get the data , and text also will get the data from textbox.
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This may solve the problem:-
code this at bottom of View

```
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```